# Matlab struct vector

Tags: matlab, octave

(I resume my question with a simple example)
I want to create a struct in matlab/octave as follows

```
c(1).x   = [0  1];
c(2).x   = [0  1];
...
c(100).x = [0  1];
```

One way is to do an for cycle:

```
for i=1:100
   c(i).x = [0 1];
end
```

My question is, how can avoid the cycle for? (The reason is that everybody knows that we need to avoid the for cycles on matlab).

Comment: The reason people usually avoid for cycles is because of the overhead compared to direct array manipulation. There is no vectorized form of this, unless you, say, replace `c.x` it with a $100\times2$ matrix. The way you've done this, you already have quite a lot of overhead, with a 100 structures and a 100 small arrays, so eliminating the for loop just isn't important.

Comment: the size of each vector c(i).x, with i=1:100 (really, I have i=1:10e4 or more), its very different (en my problem, not in the example that I showed) and, in addition, just some of them increasing during the program. For that reason I though its a good idea to have 100 structures.

Comment: I think it's quite likely that if you can afford the overhead of $10^4$ structures, then a simple for-loop is not expensive enough to worry about. Have you actually tried profiling your code and making sure that it is in fact a problem? It would be nice to see some actual timing data.

Comment: its a finite element code. This "loop" is inside of other loops. For that reason I was looking for the best way to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in Matlab:

```
N = 1e4;
c = []; c.x = [0 1]; 
c(1:N) = c;
```